# "Cannot find name 'IPost'" ServiceStack TypeScript DTOs for Auth Service

Tags: servicestack

I created my Auth Server using the following ServiceStack code:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new JwtAuthProvider
        {
            HashAlgorithm = AuthSettings.HashAlgorithm,
            RequireSecureConnection = requireSecureConnection,
            AuthKeyBase64 = AuthSettings.JwtAuthKeyBase64,
            ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
            ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireRefreshTokensIn"].ToDouble()),
            CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
                    payload["zipCode"] = ((CustomUserSession)session).ZipCode;
            },
            PopulateSessionFilter = AuthSettings.PopulateSessionFilterImplementation
        },
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider((ITsoContext)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITsoContext))) //HTML Form post of User/Pass
    }));
```

Very straightforward, I then rendered my Typescript "dtos.ts" from my http://runningauthservice/types.

I am using [servicestack-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client) version 0.0.40

This is the first time I have seen IPost in any dtos.ts I render from a ServiceStack api of mine, here is a snippet of my auth dto.ts:

```
// @Route("/assignroles")
// @DataContract
export class AssignRoles implements IReturn<AssignRolesResponse>, IPost
{
    // @DataMember(Order=1)
    userName: string;

    // @DataMember(Order=2)
    permissions: string[];

    // @DataMember(Order=3)
    roles: string[];
    createResponse() { return new AssignRolesResponse(); }
    getTypeName() { return "AssignRoles"; }
}
```

And a snippet of the Typescript error in Visual Code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue [should be resolved](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/typescript-ref-doesnt-define-iget-ipost/4701) with the latest pre-release packages on MyGet. Please review [ServiceStack v5 changes](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) before upgrading.